# Display in app URL result data from server

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nsurlsession

I have set up a arduino server that receives a http request such as "192.168.0.1/bulbON" and does certain action returning me the result of such action. Everything seems to be working fine, and I get the corresponding message in the console : optional(bulb 1 is ON)

I would like to display this information in my app in a table view or something. What would be the best way to do that?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var ON: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var OFF: UIImageView!


@IBAction fun lightON(sender: AnyObject) {

    ON.hidden = false;
    StatusLampada.hidden = true;

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.0.210/lightON")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
        println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    }

    task.resume()


}


@IBAction fun lightOFF(sender: AnyObject) {


    ON.hidden = true;
    OFF.hidden = false;


    let url = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.0.210/bublOFF")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
        println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    }

    task.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have an `Array<String>` property in your view controller and when you receive the response, you add the string to the array.

After adding the string to the array, call `tableView.reloadData`. This will cause the table view to call all the table view data source and delegate methods again.

At that point, it's just a matter of your table view customizing its cells from your array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to add the UITableView to your storyboard and link it to your view controller you could get this done quickly by doing the following:

```
//update class to conform to UITableViewDataSource protocol
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
```

Add a property to your class with a property observer which automatically reloads the table when you add to the array.

```
var statusArray:[String] = [String]() { didSet { self.tableView.reloadData()} }
```

Then implement the two required methods for UITableViewDataSource:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return statusArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StatusCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.text = statusArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Then in your completion handlers, instead of `println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))`

```
statusArray.append(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String)
```